# Incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct compartido'

Tags: c, pointers, multiprocessing

I have one problem with this code. I should create one structure and share it across 5 new process created from the father:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <time.h>

struct compartido {
    int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4, pid5;   
    int propietario;            
    int contador;                   
    int pidpadre;
};

struct compartido var;  


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    key_t llave1,llavesem;
    int idmem,idsem;    
    llave1=ftok("/tmp",'a');

    idmem=shmget(llave1,sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT|0600);
    if (idmem==-1) {
       perror ("shmget");
       return 1;
    }

var=shmat(idmem,0,0); /*This line is giving the error*/

/*rest of the code*/
}
```

The exact error is giving is: 
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct compartido' from type 'void *'

I need to put this structure in the shared variable to be able to see and modify all those data from the 6 process (5 children and the father).

What I'm doing bad? Thanks in advance and best regards,

Comment: If you have that on your platform, the modern `shm_open` combined with `mmap` is preferable over `shmget` etc, since it has no restrictions on sizes and uses file descriptors and not special "keys".

Comment: It would have been nice to give English like comments and names in your code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should declare a pointer

```
 struct compartido* var;
```

then initialize it with

```
 var= (struct compartido*) shmat(idmem,0,0);
```

You should handle the error case

```
 if ((void*)var == (void*)-1) {
    perror("shmat failed");
    exit(1);
 }
```

since [shmat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shmat.2.html) is (on Linux) a [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) which can fail.

At last, use pointer field notation to access the fields, e.g. `var->propietario` or `var->pidpatre` etc...

Comment: First: thank you so much for your quick answers.

I've tried all them and all solve the problem I face, but when I change it I got this new problem when I tried to look/modify the variables inside the structure:

var.pidpadre=getpid();

error: request for member 'pidpadre' in something not a structure or union.

So, now I've got the structure created but I'm not able to use it! :-SS

Can you please, help me?

Thanks again!

Comment: As I suggested, use `var->pidpatre` insteead of `var.pidpatre`

Comment: ok, I think I've got it. Instead using var.pidpadre ..... use var->pidpadre. I though it does the same :-S

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign the structure var with the return value of shmat() which is a void *

I suspect you are missing an indirection?

[See Basile's "snap" post which is more elaborate]

Comment: wrong, `shmat` returns a generic pointer `(void*)` (except on failure)

Comment: Correct... chunky fingers on my part!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a pointer to a structure variable.
I'd do the following:

```
idmem=shmget(llave1,sizeof(struct compartido),IPC_CREAT|0600);
if (idmem==-1) {
   perror ("shmget");
   return 1;
}
struct compartido *var=shmat(idmem,0,0);
```

Note that you're allocating less than struct compartido size in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you're doing is bad:

This line is declaring a structure -

```
struct compartido var;
```

Then you're assigning a pointer to it:

```
var=shmat(idmem,0,0); //returns a void*
```

Checkout how [shmat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat) works